# MySQL query to get a list of all permissible user privileges

Tags: mysql, privileges

Is there a MySQL query to get a list of all permissible user privileges?
Like the one shown on this [MySQL page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#idm140316879048512)?

Comment: I'm over-analyzing this question, but are you asking if there's a query (similar to something like `DESCRIBE mysql.tables_priv;`) that will show you what privileges are allowed to be given to the DB users (like [`GRANT`/`REVOKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html#grant-privileges),etc.), or are you asking to see what DB users have which privileges on which columns/tables?

Comment: yes I'm looking for something similar to `DESCRIBE mysql.tables_priv;` but more in the way of the table in the page I linked. The best would be to get an array like `array('PRIVILEGES'=>array('CREATE', 'DROP', 'GRANT OPTION', 'etc...'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SHOW PRIVILEGES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-privileges.html) will give you a list of privileges supported on a mysql server.